# toggle button to start/stop refreshing my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make sort of a toggle button to start and stop a page from refreshing itself but for some reason the stopping process isn't working. is my logic correct?

this is my code:

```
<button id = "toggleButton" onclick = "initRefresh()" >  Stop Refresh </button>

    <script>
    function reloadUrl() {
        window.location.replace(
            [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('')
        );

    }


    function initRefresh() {
        if ($('#toggleButton').text() == 'Start Refresh') {
            $('#toggleButton').text("Stop Refresh");
            t = window.setTimeout(reloadUrl, 45000);
        } else {
            $('#toggleButton').text("Start Refresh");
            clearTimeout(t);
        }
    };

    var t = window.setTimeout(reloadUrl, 45000); 

</script>
```

the default option (on first load) is on. so when the user goes into the page for the first time 45 seconds later the page will refresh.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468122/jquery-stop-settimeout-if-user-clicks-in-input-field

Comment: It is working in my case. Whenever I'm stopping it, It stops refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes from the initialization of the `t` variable.
You start a setTimeout when the page loads.

Change it to `var t = null` and the above code should work.

Comment: if I change it to "var t = null" the page won't automatically reload after 45 sec?

Comment: so wont there be a problem with every refresh interval the user will need to restart the process?

Answer (score 0):

Your code (as in question) is working 100%.

But it will not work if placed your code inside `$(document).ready` event.